# How to Build OpenSSL for iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, macos, security, openssl

I have been trying to figure out how to create/build static and dynamic OpenSSL libraries for apple platform i.e iOS and osx but unable to find any proper documentation.

I need to build the 1.1.1i version of openssl or any 1.1.1 equivalent.

Tried to follow this https://github.com/keeshux/openssl-apple but then it fails while building MAC-OSX arm64.

Can anybody please point me right/working direction??

Thanks!!

Comment: This repo looks fairly well maintained , what target you are using exactly during build.

Comment: This is what it takes by default when we run build-libssl.sh..
Targets: ios-sim-cross-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64e
macos64-x86_64 macos64-arm64
mac-catalyst-x86_64 mac-catalyst-arm64
watchos-cross-armv7k watchos-cross-arm64_32 watchos-sim-cross-x86_64 watchos-sim-cross-i386
tvos-sim-cross-x86_64 tvos64-cross-arm64 ...... Fails for arm64 macos

Answer (score 3):

This script may help.  It builds the OpenSSL 1.1.1 and 1.0.2 series libraries ([reference](https://github.com/jasonacox/Build-OpenSSL-cURL#openssl) - also has build script for OSX)

## iOS Build

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script downloads and builds the iOS openSSL libraries with Bitcode enabled
#
# Author: Jason Cox, @jasonacox https://github.com/jasonacox/Build-OpenSSL-cURL
# Date: 2020-Aug-15
#

set -e

# Custom build options
CUSTOMCONFIG="enable-ssl-trace"

# Formatting
default="\033[39m"
white="\033[97m"
green="\033[32m"
red="\033[91m"
yellow="\033[33m"

bold="\033[0m${green}\033[1m"
subbold="\033[0m${green}"
archbold="\033[0m${yellow}\033[1m"
normal="${white}\033[0m"
dim="\033[0m${white}\033[2m"
alert="\033[0m${red}\033[1m"
alertdim="\033[0m${red}\033[2m"

# set trap to help debug build errors
trap 'echo -e "${alert}** ERROR with Build - Check /tmp/openssl*.log${alertdim}"; tail -3 /tmp/openssl*.log' INT TERM EXIT

# Set minimum OS versions for target
MACOS_X86_64_VERSION=""         # Empty = use host version
MACOS_ARM64_VERSION=""          # Min supported is MacOS 11.0 Big Sur
CATALYST_IOS="13.0"             # Min supported is iOS 13.0 for Mac Catalyst
IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION="8.0"
IOS_SDK_VERSION=""
TVOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION="9.0"
TVOS_SDK_VERSION=""
catalyst="0"
VERSION="1.1.1i"                # OpenSSL version default

CORES=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
OPENSSL_VERSION="openssl-${VERSION}"

if [ -z "${MACOS_X86_64_VERSION}" ]; then
    MACOS_X86_64_VERSION=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
fi
if [ -z "${MACOS_ARM64_VERSION}" ]; then
    MACOS_ARM64_VERSION=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
fi

usage ()
{
    echo
    echo -e "${bold}Usage:${normal}"
    echo
    echo -e "  ${subbold}$0${normal} [-v ${dim}<version>${normal}] [-s ${dim}<version>${normal}] [-t ${dim}<version>${normal}] [-i ${dim}<version>${normal}] [-a ${dim}<version>${normal}] [-u ${dim}<version>${normal}]  [-e] [-m] [-3] [-x] [-h]"
    echo
    echo "         -v   version of OpenSSL (default $VERSION)"
    echo "         -s   iOS min target version (default $IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION)"
    echo "         -t   tvOS min target version (default $TVOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION)"
    echo "         -i   macOS 86_64 min target version (default $MACOS_X86_64_VERSION)"
    echo "         -a   macOS arm64 min target version (default $MACOS_ARM64_VERSION)"
    echo "         -e   compile with engine support"
    echo "         -m   compile Mac Catalyst library"
    echo "         -u   Mac Catalyst iOS min target version (default $CATALYST_IOS)"
    echo "         -3   compile with SSLv3 support"
    echo "         -x   disable color output"
    echo "         -h   show usage"
    echo
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
    exit 127
}

engine=0

while getopts "v:s:t:i:a:u:emx3h\?" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        v)
            OPENSSL_VERSION="openssl-${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        s)
            IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        t)
            TVOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        i)
            MACOS_X86_64_VERSION="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        a)
            MACOS_ARM64_VERSION="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        e)
            engine=1
            ;;
        m)
            catalyst="1"
            ;;
        u)
            catalyst="1"
            CATALYST_IOS="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        x)
            bold=""
            subbold=""
            normal=""
            dim=""
            alert=""
            alertdim=""
            archbold=""
            ;;
        3)
            CUSTOMCONFIG="enable-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method enable-ssl-trace"
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`

# Semantic Version Comparison
version_lte() {
    [  "$1" = "`echo -e "$1\n$2" | sort -V | head -n1`" ]
}
if version_lte $MACOS_ARM64_VERSION 11.0; then
        MACOS_ARM64_VERSION="11.0"      # Min support for Apple Silicon is 11.0
fi

buildIOS()
{
    ARCH=$1

    pushd . > /dev/null
    cd "${OPENSSL_VERSION}"

    if [[ "${ARCH}" == "i386" || "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ]]; then
        PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
    else
        PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
        #sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!static volatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"
    fi

    export $PLATFORM
    export CROSS_TOP="${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer"
    export CROSS_SDK="${PLATFORM}${IOS_SDK_VERSION}.sdk"
    export BUILD_TOOLS="${DEVELOPER}"
    export CC="${BUILD_TOOLS}/usr/bin/gcc -fembed-bitcode -arch ${ARCH}"

    echo -e "${subbold}Building ${OPENSSL_VERSION} for ${PLATFORM} ${IOS_SDK_VERSION} ${archbold}${ARCH}${dim} (iOS ${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION})"

    if [[ "${ARCH}" == "i386" || "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ]]; then
        TARGET="darwin-i386-cc"
        if [[ $ARCH == "x86_64" ]]; then
            TARGET="darwin64-x86_64-cc"
        fi
        if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
            ./Configure no-asm ${TARGET} -no-shared --prefix="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log"
        else
            ./Configure no-asm ${TARGET} -no-shared --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log"
        fi
    else
        if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
            # export CC="${BUILD_TOOLS}/usr/bin/gcc -arch ${ARCH}"
            ./Configure iphoneos-cross DSO_LDFLAGS=-fembed-bitcode --prefix="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" -no-shared --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log"
        else
            ./Configure iphoneos-cross -no-shared --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log"
        fi
    fi
    # add -isysroot to CC=
    if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
        sed -ie "s!^CFLAGS=!CFLAGS=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION} !" "Makefile"
    else
        sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION} !" "Makefile"
    fi

    make -j${CORES} >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    make install_sw >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    make clean >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    popd > /dev/null

    # Clean up exports
    export PLATFORM=""
    export CC=""
    export CXX=""
    export CFLAGS=""
    export LDFLAGS=""
    export CPPFLAGS=""
    export CROSS_TOP=""
    export CROSS_SDK=""
    export BUILD_TOOLS=""
}

buildIOSsim()
{
    ARCH=$1

    pushd . > /dev/null
    cd "${OPENSSL_VERSION}"

    PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
    export $PLATFORM

    TARGET="darwin-i386-cc"
    RUNTARGET=""
    MIPHONEOS="${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION}"
    if [[ $ARCH != "i386" ]]; then
        TARGET="darwin64-${ARCH}-cc"
        RUNTARGET="-target ${ARCH}-apple-ios${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION}-simulator"
            # e.g. -target arm64-apple-ios11.0-simulator
        #if [[ $ARCH == "arm64" ]]; then
        #   if (( $(echo "${MIPHONEOS} < 11.0" |bc -l) )); then
        #       MIPHONEOS="11.0"    # Min support for Apple Silicon is iOS 11.0 
        #   fi
        #fi
    fi
    
    # set up exports for build 
    export CFLAGS=" -Os -miphoneos-version-min=${MIPHONEOS} -fembed-bitcode -arch ${ARCH} ${RUNTARGET} "
    export LDFLAGS=" -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk "
    export CPPFLAGS=" -I.. -isysroot ${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk "
    export CROSS_TOP="${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer"
    export CROSS_SDK="${PLATFORM}${IOS_SDK_VERSION}.sdk"
    export BUILD_TOOLS="${DEVELOPER}"
    export CC="${BUILD_TOOLS}/usr/bin/gcc"
    export CXX="${BUILD_TOOLS}/usr/bin/gcc"

    echo -e "${subbold}Building ${OPENSSL_VERSION} for ${PLATFORM} ${iOS_SDK_VERSION} ${archbold}${ARCH}${dim} (iOS ${MIPHONEOS})"

    # configure
    if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
        ./Configure no-asm ${TARGET} -no-shared --prefix="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}" --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}.log"
    else
        ./Configure no-asm ${TARGET} -no-shared --openssldir="/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}" $CUSTOMCONFIG &> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}.log"
    fi

    # add -isysroot to CC=
    # no longer needed with exports
    #if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
    #   sed -ie "s!^CFLAGS=!CFLAGS=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION} !" "Makefile"
    #else
    #   sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} -miphoneos-version-min=${IOS_MIN_SDK_VERSION} !" "Makefile"
    #fi

    # make
    make -j${CORES} >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    make install_sw >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    make clean >> "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-${ARCH}.log" 2>&1
    popd > /dev/null

    # Clean up exports
    export PLATFORM=""
    export CC=""
    export CXX=""
    export CFLAGS=""
    export LDFLAGS=""
    export CPPFLAGS=""
    export CROSS_TOP=""
    export CROSS_SDK=""
    export BUILD_TOOLS=""
}

#echo -e "${bold}Cleaning up${dim}"
#rm -rf include/openssl/* lib/*

mkdir -p Mac/lib
mkdir -p Catalyst/lib
mkdir -p iOS/lib
mkdir -p iOS-simulator/lib
mkdir -p iOS-fat/lib
mkdir -p tvOS/lib
mkdir -p Mac/include/openssl/
mkdir -p Catalyst/include/openssl/
mkdir -p iOS/include/openssl/
mkdir -p iOS-simulator/include/openssl/
mkdir -p iOS-fat/include/openssl/
mkdir -p tvOS/include/openssl/

rm -rf "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-*"
rm -rf "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-*.log"

rm -rf "${OPENSSL_VERSION}"

if [ ! -e ${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz ]; then
    echo "Downloading ${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz"
    curl -LOs https://www.openssl.org/source/${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz
else
    echo "Using ${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz"
fi

if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.1.1"* ]]; then
    echo "** Building OpenSSL 1.1.1 **"
else
    if [[ "$OPENSSL_VERSION" = "openssl-1.0."* ]]; then
        echo "** Building OpenSSL 1.0.x ** "
        echo -e "${alert}** WARNING: End of Life Version - Upgrade to 1.1.1 **${dim}"
    else
        echo -e "${alert}** WARNING: This build script has not been tested with $OPENSSL_VERSION **${dim}"
    fi
fi

echo "Unpacking openssl"
tar xfz "${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz"

if [ "$engine" == "1" ]; then
    echo "+ Activate Static Engine"
    sed -ie 's/\"engine/\"dynamic-engine/' ${OPENSSL_VERSION}/Configurations/15-ios.conf
fi

echo -e "${bold}Building iOS libraries${dim}"
buildIOS "armv7"
buildIOS "armv7s"
buildIOS "arm64"
buildIOS "arm64e"

buildIOSsim "i386"
buildIOSsim "x86_64"
buildIOSsim "arm64"

echo "  Copying headers and libraries"
cp /tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/include/openssl/* iOS/include/openssl/

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7s/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64e/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    -create -output iOS/lib/libcrypto.a

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7s/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64e/lib/libssl.a" \
    -create -output iOS/lib/libssl.a


cp /tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-x86_64/include/openssl/* iOS-simulator/include/openssl/

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-i386/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-arm64/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    -create -output iOS-simulator/lib/libcrypto.a

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-i386/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-x86_64/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-arm64/lib/libssl.a" \
    -create -output iOS-simulator/lib/libssl.a

cp /tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/include/openssl/* iOS-fat/include/openssl/

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7s/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64e/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-i386/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a" \
    -create -output iOS-fat/lib/libcrypto.a

lipo \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-armv7s/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-arm64e/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-x86_64/lib/libssl.a" \
    "/tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-iOS-Simulator-i386/lib/libssl.a" \
    -create -output iOS-fat/lib/libssl.a

echo "  Creating combined OpenSSL libraries for iOS"
libtool -no_warning_for_no_symbols -static -o openssl-ios-armv7_armv7s_arm64_arm64e.a iOS/lib/libcrypto.a iOS/lib/libssl.a
libtool -no_warning_for_no_symbols -static -o openssl-ios-i386_x86_64_arm64-simulator.a iOS-simulator/lib/libcrypto.a iOS-simulator/lib/libssl.a

echo -e "${bold}Cleaning up${dim}"
rm -rf /tmp/${OPENSSL_VERSION}-*
rm -rf ${OPENSSL_VERSION}

#reset trap
trap - INT TERM EXIT

echo -e "${normal}Done"
```

Note:
The overarching [project](https://github.com/jasonacox/Build-OpenSSL-cURL) builds OpenSSL, nghttp2 and cURL/libcurl for MacOS (x86_64, arm64), Mac Catalyst (x86_64, arm64), iOS (armv7, armv7s, arm64 and arm64e), iOS Simulator (x86_64, arm64), tvOS (arm64) and tvOS Simulator (x86_64). Update now builds XCFrameworks which supports all platforms and targets for easy import into your projects.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30475382)

Comment: Works with OpenSSL 3.0.7, XCode 13.1, OS Monterey, as long as you 1) remove `-embed-bitcode` (which is deprecated in XCode 14 anyway), 2) comment out the "if openssl 1.1.1" and their else's, so that it's assumed to be v1.1.1, and 3) run the script as `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use LibreSSL instead

Granted, this is not a 1.1 version of OpenSSL, but if you're not familiar with [LibreSSL](http://www.libressl.org) it is a drop-in replacement for OpenSSL 1.0.x and I think is easier to work with from a compilation standpoint, because it relies on CMake.

Building for macOS would not necessarily require a toolchain file.

You need to do three things

- Modify the CMakeLists.txt to generate a framework (if desired)
- Provide a toolchain file for each SDK
- Combine the output into an XCFramework - optional

I have applied the following snippet to the source root `CMakeLists.txt` as a [Pull Request](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/pull/693).

```
if (BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK)
    # Trick cmake into doing work - like copying the headers
    set(EMPTY_C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/empty.c)
    file(TOUCH ${EMPTY_C})

    set(MODULE_MODULEMAP ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/module.modulemap)
    file(WRITE ${MODULE_MODULEMAP} "\
framework module LibreSSL {
    umbrella header \"LibreSSL.h\"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
")
    set_source_files_properties(${MODULE_MODULEMAP} PROPERTIES
            MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Modules)

    # Create the umbrella header
    set(LIBRESSL_H ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibreSSL.h)
    file(REMOVE ${LIBRESSL_H})
    file(GLOB LIBRESSL_INCLUDES
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/*.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/openssl/*.h)

    foreach(LIBRESSL_INCLUDE ${LIBRESSL_INCLUDES})
        file(RELATIVE_PATH RELATIVE_INCLUDE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include ${LIBRESSL_INCLUDE})
        get_filename_component(RELATIVE_INCLUDE_DIR ${RELATIVE_INCLUDE} DIRECTORY)
        set_source_files_properties(${LIBRESSL_INCLUDE} PROPERTIES
                    MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Headers/${RELATIVE_INCLUDE_DIR})
        file(APPEND ${LIBRESSL_H} "#include \"${RELATIVE_INCLUDE}\"\n")
    endforeach()

    # Create the framework from object libraries
    add_library(LibreSSL_framework ${EMPTY_C}
            $<TARGET_OBJECTS:crypto_obj> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ssl_obj>
            ${LIBRESSL_H} ${LIBRESSL_INCLUDES}
            ${MODULE_MODULEMAP})
    set_target_properties(LibreSSL_framework PROPERTIES
            OUTPUT_NAME LibreSSL
            PUBLIC_HEADER "${LIBRESSL_H}"
            FRAMEWORK on)

    install(TARGETS LibreSSL_framework
            FRAMEWORK DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
endif(BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK)
```

### generate_xcframework.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

FRAMEWORKS=()
for SDK in macosx iphoneos iphonesimulator; do
    BUILD_DIR=build-${SDK}
    rm -rf ${BUILD_DIR}
    mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR} 
    pushd ${BUILD_DIR}
    cmake -G Ninja -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/${SDK}.toolchain.cmake ..
    cmake --build . --target LibreSSL_framework
    FRAMEWORKS+=(-framework ${BUILD_DIR}/LibreSSL.framework)
    popd
done

XCFRAMEWORK_DIR=build-xcframework
rm -rf ${XCFRAMEWORK_DIR}
mkdir -p ${XCFRAMEWORK_DIR}
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    "${FRAMEWORKS[@]}" \
    -output ${XCFRAMEWORK_DIR}/LibreSSL.xcframework
```

### macosx.toolchain.cmake

```
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin )
set( SDK macosx CACHE STRING "Xcode SDK" )

set( CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64 arm64 CACHE STRING "Architectures" )
```

### iphoneos.toolchain.cmake

```
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin )
set( SDK iphoneos CACHE STRING "Xcode SDK" )

set( CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES armv7 armv7s arm64 CACHE STRING "Architectures" )

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/apple-common-toolchain.cmake)
```

### iphonesimulator.toolchain.cmake

```
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin )
set( SDK iphonesimulator CACHE STRING "Xcode SDK" )

set( CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64 CACHE STRING "Architectures" )

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/apple-common-toolchain.cmake)
```

### apple-common-toolchain.cmake

```
set(BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK on)

if(SDK STREQUAL iphoneos OR SDK STREQUAL iphonesimulator)
    set(IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "9.0")
    set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ${IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
elseif(SDK STREQUAL macosx)
    set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.10" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown sdk when setting deployment target: ${SDK}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS on)

execute_process(COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --find clang
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_C_COMPILER
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} CACHE PATH "clang executable")

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --find clang++
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} CACHE PATH "clang++ executable")

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --find libtool
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_LIBTOOL
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_LIBTOOL ${CMAKE_LIBTOOL} CACHE PATH "libtool executable")

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --find strip
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_STRIP
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_STRIP ${CMAKE_STRIP} CACHE PATH "strip executable")

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --find dsymutil
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE DSYMUTIL
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
if( BUILD_TARGET_IOS AND NOT BUILD_TARGET_SIMULATOR)
    if( XCODE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 11)
        set(DSYMUTIL ${DSYMUTIL} -t 1)
    endif()
endif()
set(DSYMUTIL ${DSYMUTIL} CACHE PATH "dsymutil executable")

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --show-sdk-path
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} CACHE PATH "sysroot")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set(CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)

set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK FIRST)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```